# Class deletion in cmd but not in IDLE

Tags: python, oop, class

When I run this code in the command prompt, the `Person` I create is automatically deleted, but when in IDLE the deletion does not occur. Why?

NOTE: This is a program that is supposed to create an address book (a list of dictionaries)

Here is my code:
list = []

```
class bookEntry(dict):
    total = 0

    def __init__(self):
        bookEntry.total += 1
        self.d = {}

    def __del__(self):
        bookEntry.total -= 1
        list.remove(self)

class Person(bookEntry):
    def __init__(self, n):
        bookEntry.__init__(self)
        self.n = n
        print '%s has been created' % (self.n)

    def __del__(self):
        print '%s has been deleted' % (self.n)

    def addnewperson(self, n, e = '', ph = '', note = ''):
        self.d['name'] = n
        self.d['email'] = e
        self.d['phone'] = ph
        self.d['note'] = note

        list.append(self)
```

I run the code with a `startup` function:

```
def startup():
    aor = raw_input('Hello! Would you like to add an entry or retrieve one?')
    if aor == 'add':
        info = raw_input('Would you like to add a person or a company?')
        if info == 'person':
            n = raw_input('Please enter this persons name:')
            e = raw_input('Please enter this persons email address:')
            ph = raw_input('Please enter this persons phone number:')
            note = raw_input('Please add any notes if applicable:')

            X = Person(n)
            X.addnewperson(n, e, ph, note)
startup()
```

When the code is run in IDLE I receive the following prompts, and submit the following answers:

```
'''
    Hello! Would you like to add an entry or retrieve one?add
    Would you like to add a person or a company?person
    Please enter this persons name:Pig
    Please enter this persons email address:pig@brickhouse.com
    Please enter this persons phone number:333-333-3333
    Please add any notes if applicable:one of three
    Pig has been created
'''
```

Here, Pig is created and is not deleted. But in cmd.....

```
'''
    Hello! Would you like to add an entry or retrieve one?add
    Would you like to add a person or a company?person
    Please enter this persons name:Pig
    Please enter this persons email address:pig@brickhouse.com
    Please enter this persons phone number:333-333-3333
    Please add any notes if applicable:one of three
    Pig has been created
    Pig has been deleted
'''
```

Why is Pig being deleted?? `__del__` is never called...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the program ends, all variables are automatically deleted (otherwise, there would be a memory leak). IDLE keeps the environment open so you can keep using the variables you've created.

*Note:* My original answer was mistaken- I missed the lines

```
list = []
```

and

```
list.append(self)
```

Comment: @DavidRobinson--Ahh i see. What might be a solution here? append X to the list? If I simply return X without appending it how can I retrieve it later on?

Comment: Sorry- like I said, the problem wasn't that it was deleting after the function was returned (you did add it to the list variable), it was just deleting *when the program ended*. There is no need for a solution- if you write more code, the variable will still exist (it's not like you needed it to exist after your entire program ended!)

Answer (score 1):

While you run in IDLE, the python process is still running even after you execute this program unless you exit from IDLE. But in command line, the python process executes your program and exits itself. So, that is where `__del__`  comes into play. When the reference count of the object is zero, it is automatically called to destroy it. so your object is deleted. When your program is ended and python process is itself terminated, there is no need for it to exist as well.

[**Reference**](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__del__)